# Asp.net MVC how to call a controller method from view to get a return Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to retrieve database table rows and show up at view, I have a main view called Index.cshtml which is my main page, i have included another view in this view called Driverview.cshtml by `@{Html.RenderPartial`
For Driverview.cshtml I have separate controller and for main page view which index.cshtml have another controller
My problem is I can not fire/call DriverController Method for Driverview, the Method is

```
public ActionResult Driverview()
```

Here is My Model

```
public class DriverViewModel
{   
    public string DriverName { get; set; }   
    public string DriverEmail { get; set; }    
}
```

Here is Driver controller for driverview

```
public ActionResult Driverview()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var model = new List<DriverViewModel>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * from Drivers";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var driver = new DriverViewModel();
                    driver.DriverName = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    driver.DriverEmail = rdr["Email"].ToString();


                    model.Add(driver);
                }

            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is DriverView to show driver data from database

```
 @using myapp.Models;
 @model List<DriverViewModel>

 @foreach (var drs in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="name"><img src="/img/main/driver_car/driver1.png">@drs.DriverName</td>
                <td class="email">@drs.DriverEmail</td>

            </tr>
        }
```

My problem is that I can not call  `public ActionResult Driverview()` from Driverview to get the Model variable which have returned from this method since i am using driverview at main view 
Please help me

Comment: Can you start by refactoring to not query directly from controller action?

Comment: Use @{Html.RenderAction("Driverview");}   instead of Html.RenderPartial on your parent view for rendering a partial view by calling controller action method.

Comment: @AnkitSahrawat I am getting the following exception when i use it
Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.